# Athom - flashing your own firmware

Tags: smart-plugs

I've bought Athom's Curtain and 4 gang touch wall switch. Both came pre-flashed with Tasmota. I guessed that UART's pins will be exposed more clrealy, but not. I'm looking for manuals such guide, or any PIC to point UART's pins.

Guy

Comment: what exactly is your question? ... please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are asking people to do internet search for you

Comment: it would make more sense to ask about the problem itself and present clear pictures of both sides of the board

Comment: @jsotola A long internet research was done. Couldn't find a single manual for relevant models.

Comment: then edit your post and focus on determining where the pins are, instead on focusing where the documentation is